# Gson - JsonObject with null values

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I am a little confused about how Gson is parsing Strings to JSON.
At the very start, I initialize gson like this

```
val gson = Gson().newBuilder().serializeNulls().disableHtmlEscaping().create()
```

Next, I'm converting my map to a String:

```
val pushJson = gson.toJson(data) // data is of type Map<String,Any>
```

That gives the following output:

```
{
    "name": null,
    "uuid": "5a8e8202-6654-44d9-a452-310773da78c1",
    "paymentCurrency": "EU"
}
```

At this point, the JSON string has null values. But in the following step:

```
val jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(pushJson).asJsonObject
```

it hasn't!

```
{
    "uuid": "5a8e8202-6654-44d9-a452-310773da78c1",
    "paymentCurrency": "EU"
}
```

Nulls are omitted. How to get all null values in JsonObject like in JSON string:

```
{
  "string-key": null,
  "other-key": null
}
```

@Edit

Added some json's to help understand the issue.

Comment: could you please paste some code that could reproduce the issue? I don't quite understand what the problem is

Comment: sure, I've edited the question

Comment: have you tried this : `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();`

Comment: Yes, as you can see this is the first line of my question :)

Comment: @shurrok what version of GSON are you using?

Comment: The latest one: 2.8.6

Comment: @shurrok thanks. Last question: how are you transforming `jsonObject` to a String? Are you simply printing it to console, using a `JsonWriter` or something else?

Comment: I am not transforming `jsonObject` to a `String`. Why would I?

Comment: I am passing `jsonObject` to an API call

Comment: ok so the issue is in the piece of code that performs the API call, as it must re-serialise the `jsonObject` to a String to perform the HTTP call. Could you paste that code as well?

Comment: Wait, gonna check if that's the case indeed

Comment: Well, that's true!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203325/discussion-between-user2340612-and-shurrok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with the OP it came out that the JSON object was then serialised by Retrofit to allow for an API call, using the following code:

```
return Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("api/url")
    .client(httpClient.build())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
    .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
```

The issue here lays in the `GsonConverterFactory`: since no `Gson` object is passed to the `create` method, a new default `Gson` instance gets created under the hood, and by default it doesn't serialise `null` values.

The issue can be easily solved by passing the appropriate instance to the factory:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create() // plus any other custom configuration
....

fun createRetrofit() = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("api/url")
    .client(httpClient.build())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)) // use the configured Gson instance
    .build()
    .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
```